# Deriving rules from facts(Logic programming)

Tags: prolog, logic

I started learning logical programming, and intrested if some of the rules can be obtained from the dataset. For example

there are following facts

```
// assume programming language, doesn't know what numbers are
IS(1, INDEX)
IS(2, INDEX)
IS(3, INDEX)
IS(4, INDEX)

// add some relations between numbers, for e.g. next number after 1 is 2, after 2 is 3, and so on
NEXT(1,2)
NEXT(2,3)
NEXT(3,4)


IS_ODD(1, TRUE)
IS_ODD(2, FALSE)
IS_ODD(3, TRUE)
IS_ODD(4, FALSE)
```

so, from these facts, I would like to know is there any algorithm/approach that can help to derive for example the following rule

```
IS_ODD(B, FALSE) :- IS_ODD(A, true), NEXT(A, B)
```

Comment: Maybe useful links: https://github.com/logic-and-learning-lab/Popper and https://github.com/stassa/louise and https://github.com/friguzzi/cplint

Comment: That is not Prolog syntax. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to write these predicate names (`IS_ODD`, `IS`, `NEXT`)  in lower case. Otherwise Prolog will think that those are variables.

Second, I assume you want to encode Peano axioms. You could use decimal notation for the numbers but then you have to use Prologs built-in arithmetic to work with them. How do you get from `10` to `11`, unless you enumerate all infinitely many successor relations? You kind of have to use `+`. But that's kind of circular. You want do derive addition from scratch right?

How about this approach

```
is(0).
is(succ(N)) :- is(N).

is_odd(succ(0)).
is_odd(succ(succ(N))) :- is_odd(N).
```

Now you can do queries like

```
?- is_odd(succ(succ(succ(0)))).
true
```

```
?- is(Nat).
Nat = 0 ;
Nat = succ(0) ;
Nat = succ(succ(0)) ;
Nat = succ(succ(succ(0))) ;
Nat = succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))) ;
Nat = succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0))))) ;
...
```

Don't think of `succ()` as a function or predicate or anything that is executed somehow. It's just serves as a wrapper or container here. You can also just call it `s()` or `next()` or whatever you want.

Try in SWISH: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/peano-axioms.pl

Comment: yeah, but the question was not about numbers in particular, the question was more about how to get some kind of patterns from these facts.
another example is(let's assume, that it's not a true prolog syntax, but just a pseudocode)
`
human(Socrat)
human(Ben)
human(Alex)
human(Eva)

mortal(Socrat)
mortal(Ben)
mortal(Alex)
mortal(Eva)
`

so, in this case, program should somehow make an assumption, that all humans are mortal and create a rule like mortal(A) :- human(A)

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with this. Prolog can definitely reason about "it's own code" with predicates like `clause`. You might want to check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmBkU-l1zyc 

I don't know how you could efficiently discover "new correlations" between rules and facts. You could enumerate all kinds of `Head :- Body` combinations and check if they hold but I suspect the search space for this quickly explodes. Sounds rather like a machine learning task to me.